# Moving an UIView containing Buttons stops Buttons responding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have an XIB file containing a subview (footerButtonsView) containing two buttons. I change the position of the subview like so:

```
if (footerView.frame.origin.y < 280.0) {    
    [footerButtonsView setFrame:CGRectMake(footerButtonsView.frame.origin.x, footerButtonsView.frame.origin.y+300.0-footerView.frame.origin.y, footerButtonsView.frame.size.width, footerButtonsView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

This moves the view containing the buttons as expected but the buttons would not react to touches anymore. Does anyone have an idea on what I'm missing here? **Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're moving the view outside the bounds of its parent view?